# json_encode() gives special charactors like '\n'..how can i replace them in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I encoded an array using `json_encode()` function and it gave me a string like this..

```
"[{"details":"power - 2000w \nac-220-240v \/ 50-60hz\n369 degree cordless base\n","model_id":"MC-EK3428 \/ MC-EK3328"}]"
```

as you can see it contains special characters like "\n"..I want these special characters to be replaced with `""` because in `javascript` I am using the `JSON.parse();` function  to convert this string to an object..
but it gives me an error

```
syntaxerror : missing ) after argument list
```

I think this is because of the special characters in the string..how can I escape these?

Edit

```
php :
$view->jsonencoded_array = json_encode($array);
javascript :
var products = JSON.parse('<?php echo $jsonencoded_array; ?>');//this line gives me the error
```

update :

found out that the error is given in this :

```
'<?php echo $jsonencoded_array; ?>'
```

Comment: Calling JSON.parse(obj) gives you that error? Any reason why can't you replace in JS?

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Comment: post the code where youre parsing the JSON object please

Comment: My guess is that you do `JSON.parse("[{"details"...`

Comment: Cant you just use preg_replace()?

Comment: What happens when you `console.log()` the json encoded string js?

Comment: It doesn't allow me to put it in console..when I am trying to assign that to a variable it gives me the error..like     var x = '<?php echo $jsonencoded_array; ?>';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `\n` (and various other combinations) have special meaning inside a JavaScript string, and you are dumping your JSON into a JavaScript string without doing any conversion of those characters.

Since JSON is heavily inspired by JavaScript literal syntax, you can use `json_encode` to convert a PHP string into a JavaScript string.

There are some gotchas, the main one being that `</script>` can appear in a JSON text without causing any problems, but having that in the middle of your JavaScript `<script>` element is going to cause the HTML parser to cut off your JavaScript in the middle of the string … but PHP's *default* encoding rules will generate `<\/script>` which solves that problem.

So:

```
<?php
$json_array = json_encode($array);
$javascript_string = $json_encode($json_array);
?>
var products = JSON.parse(<?php echo $javascript_string; ?>);
```

That said. A JSON array is also a JavaScript array, so you can skip that step entirely.

```
<?php
$json_array = json_encode($array);
?>
var products = <?php echo $json_array; ?>;
```

Comment: Thank you very much json_encoding twice helped me... json_encode(json_encode($array));

Answer (score 1):

There must something that you are missing or there is some other reason for your issue while parsing in JavaScript; because [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)  handles `\n` and other special characters such `"` `\` etc. very well and escape them properly without any explicit work.

I would suggest you to check the JSON produced and you are supplying to JavaScript and see if there is something missing in between.

Note: You can do a [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) but it is not advised. Better stick to `json_encode`since its s standard function and it works well.

**Edit:**
You should be echoing `$view->jsonencoded_array` not just `$jsonencoded_array`, no need to parse already JSON object.

php :

```
$view->jsonencoded_array = json_encode($array);
```

javascript :

```
var products = <?php echo $view->jsonencoded_array; ?>;
```

Comment: But after encoding the array with json_encode() it gives me this result.. "[{"details":"power - 2000w \nac-220-240v \/ 50-60hz\n369 degree cordless base\n","model_id":"MC-EK3428 \/ MC-EK3328"}]"   with the new line '\n'

Comment: @SNT93 its a valid JSON there is nothing wrong with it. Validate it here: http://pro.jsonlint.com/

Comment: then why I can't assign that to a variable in javascript?and gives me the error : syntaxerror : missing ) after argument list

Comment: @SNT93 check the Edit i made it might be the reason.

Answer (score -1):

json_encode() twice helped me to solve this issue..

```
$view->jsonencoded = json_encode(json_encode($array));
```